# For loop and value changing using awk

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have the following file format

```
...
MODE P E
IMP:P 1 19r 0
IMP:E 1 19r 0
...
SDEF POS= 0 0 14.6 AXS= 0 0 1 EXT=d3 RAD= d4 cell=23 ERG=d1 PAR=2
SI1 L  0.020
SP1    1
SI4 0. 3.401                                                                    
SI3 0.9 
...
NPS 20000000
```

What I am trying to do is to locate a specific value(in particular the value after the sequence `SI1 L`) and create a series of files with different values. For instance `ST1 L 0.020`--->`ST1 L 0.050`. What I have in mind is to give a start value, an end value and a step so as to generate files with different values after the sequence `SI1 L`. For instance a for loop would work, but I don't know how to use it outside `awk`.

I am able to locate the value using

```
awk '$1=="SI1" {printf "%12s\n", $3}' file
```

I could also use the following to replace the value

```
awk '$1=="SI1" {gsub(/0.020/, "0.050"); printf "%12s\n", $3}' file
```

The thing is that the value won't always be `0.020`. That's why I need a way to replace the value after the sequence `SI1 L` and this replacement should be done for many values.

How can this be acheived?

Comment: What should be the content of the files you want to create? How are the start and end value related to the content of the files?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Thank you very much for your comment! The output file will be exactly the same as the input one, except from the different value after the sequence `SI1 L `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk -vval="0.05" '$1=="SI1"{$3=val}1' file
```

This will replace `SI1 L  0.020` by `SI1 L 0.05`  in the input file.

Then use a bash script to call the awk program in a for loop..

For instance:

```
#! /bin/bash

vals=(0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05)

i=0
for val in "${vals[@]}"; do
  i=$(($i+1))
  awk -vval="$val" '$1=="SI1"{$3=val}1' file > "file${i}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! How would the output files be generated? I used `awk -vval="$val" '$1=="SI1"{$3=val}1' file >$vals[@]` but it's not working.

Comment: @Thanos No problem :) I have updated my answer with a suggestion.. Now the files are named `file1`, `file2`, .. , and so on..

Comment: Preferably I would like the output file to be named with the name of the value at the position `i`. For instance the output files will be `0.02`, `0.03`, `0.04` and so on.

Comment: @Thanos Ok.. Then you could try `awk -vval="$val" '$1=="SI1"{$3=val}1' file > "${val}"`

Answer (score 1):

If your system has seq command, here is easier script for you.

```
for val in $(seq 0.02 0.01 0.05)
do 
  awk -vval="$val" '/SI1 L/{$3=val}1' file > "${val}"
  # or Using sed
  # sed: sed "s/SI1 L .*/SI1 L $val/" > "${val}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've noticed that you placed a `1` sfter `/SI1 L/{$3=val}1`. If I remove it I get no output. What does it do?

Comment: 1 means true, so it will print the line.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question? What does the `-vval` do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script